# How to specify the timezone in a python timestamp literal?

Tags: python, timestamp

The following works:

```
 datetime.strptime("2023-11-15 01:02:03.123456", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

> Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 15, 1, 2, 3, 123456)

But the following fails:

```
 datetime.strptime("2023-11-15 01:02:03.123456", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%Z"))
```

> ValueError: time data '2023-11-15 01:02:03.123456'
> does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%Z'

How should that timestamp literal be set up to specify `UTC-8` ?

*Update*  I also tried

```
"2023-11-15 01:02:03.123456 -08:00"
```

That did not work. I'm not sure what the syntax is here.

Comment: Well, include a timezone specification in the timestamp like `-08:00`…?!

Comment: I just tried adding that, not sure how to format it still. Updated the question

Comment: Check what `%Z` means exactly (also see `%z`)…!? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%Z` can only parse timezone names (e.g., 'UTC', 'EST', 'CST') and not offsets like 'UTC-8', you need to use `%z` (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime_str = "2023-11-15 01:02:03.123456-0800"  # UTC-8
>>> datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
>>> datetime_object
datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 15, 1, 2, 3, 123456, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=57600)))
```

***[n.b.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene)** Make sure your timezone offset string conforms to the +HHMM or -HHMM format.*